# Dynamically-added Parameter to JS File (cache-busting) Does Not Cause Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache

I've added a random date param to my CSS and JS files in order to "cache-bust"...

HTML (head)

```
<!-- STYLE -->
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style">

<!-- SCRIPTS --> 
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js" id="scripts"></script>
```

JS (jQuery 3.4.1)

```
var randomParam = new Date().getTime();
// CSS
var ogCSS = $("head").find("#style").attr("href");
$("head").find("#style").attr("href", ogCSS + "?" + randomParam);
// JS
var ogJS = $("head").find("#scripts").attr("src");
$("head").find("#scripts").attr("src", ogJS + "?" + randomParam);
```

The CSS file works great. The JS file not so much.

"Network" tab (CSS renamed and called again, JS is not)...

[image]

"Sources" tab (JS not called again, has original name)...

[image]

I cannot use PHP. I cannot access the server. This is all client-side.

What can I do to make it work? Or is this just how it is?

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention that "Elements" in the DevTools show the JS file being renamed properly (see below). It's just not being re-called in "Network" or showing up as being renamed in "Sources". So it's stuck in cache.

[image]

Comment: Can you check the script tag value in developer tools in chrome browser, i am assuming the date value you used for the JavaScript is not correct, can you use the same date value of css instead of creating again using new `new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: @CNKR - the JS file in the <head> is being renamed properly when looking at Elements in DevTools, it's just not being reflected in Network or Sources as being called again like the CSS file is. So it's stuck being cached. Using the same date value generated for both CSS and JS has no effect. Same result.

Comment: Updated question to show the JS file being renamed in <head>, just not reflecting elsewhere or being called again.

Comment: Can you check the network tab in the developer tools to make sure if the script.js with timestamp loaded successful or failed. I want to understand when the code is called to changing the src in the script tag with date.

Comment: @CNKR - I shared a picture of the "Network" tab in the question ^ - the JS file loads only with the original name. The timestamped script.js does not show at all in the Network tab. In the "Elements" tab, in the <head>, the file is being renamed (see image in the question). So, it's just renaming, but isn't being reloaded.

Comment: The script loaded before we rename the src in it. To confirm this can you put alert before changing the src with timestamp and see if the network tab already has loaded with script.js. If it so, the code to append the timestamp is in wrong place.

Comment: @CNKR - I put an alert after the CSS is renamed and an alert after the JS is renamed. This is what happens: [1] page loads, [2] CSS loads, [3] JS loads, [4] CSS is renamed and reloaded (as shown in Elements, Network, Source), [5] alert fires saying CSS is renamed (so this works), [6] alert fires saying JS is renamed, but JS is not reloaded (renamed in Elements only, new name doesn't show in Network or Sources).

Comment: can you add the script and link tags at the bottom of  the page and use `$(document).ready() `to rename the file names.

Comment: @CNKR - Deleted code from JS file, added to bottom of HTML (before </body>) as instructed - exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but in case someone comes across it (as I did), the problem is likely here:

`ogCSS + "?" + randomParam`

That does not create a valid and complete query string. The format of the query string should be:

`?<param_name>=<param_value>`

but in the code above, we only have `?<param_value>`. This means the value will be treated as a name, presumably with a null value, which is generally ignored by most servers I have worked with. To make this correct, you would need to append both a parameter name (often "_" for this use case) and a value, so something like:

`ogCSS + "?_=" + randomParam`